# MySQL for averaging missing dates

Tags: mysql, date, window-functions

I am looking to update rows where the `date` column is `NULL` by averaging the dates of the nearest id before and nearest id after that row.

In the data below, it would update the row with ID `26` to be `2011-10-19`

What MySQL statement would accomplish this?

---

## **Additional Notes:**

The data looks something like this:

```
id     date           title
--------------------------------------------
12     2011-09-01     Example One
23     2011-10-02     Example Two
26     NULL           Example Three
27     2011-11-05     Example Four
29     2012-01-05     Example Five
37     NULL           Example Six
38     2012-02-03     Example Seven
--------------------------------------------
```

I would prefer not to use a procedure.

So far I've got...

```
UPDATE `table`
    SET `date`=
         (AVG(
              (SELECT `date` FROM `table` WHERE `id`< ID_OF_PARENT_QUERY AND `date` IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1),
              (SELECT `date` FROM `table` WHERE `id`> ID_OF_PARENT_QUERY AND `date` IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1)
         ))

    WHERE `date` IS NULL
```

Comment: Can you have more than one consecutive `NULL` value? If that is the case, how would you proceed?

Comment: @MostyMostacho - Yes. I want to find the closest row (by unique id) where there IS a `date` value set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableX AS t
  JOIN tableX AS next
    ON next.id =
       ( SELECT MIN(n.id)
         FROM tableX AS n
         WHERE n.id > t.id
           AND n.dateX IS NOT NULL
       )
  JOIN tableX AS prev 
    ON prev.id =
       ( SELECT MAX(p.id)
         FROM tableX AS p
         WHERE p.id < t.id
           AND p.dateX IS NOT NULL
       )
SET t.dateX = prev.dateX + INTERVAL (DATEDIFF(next.dateX, prev.dateX) / 2) DAY
WHERE t.dateX IS NULL
```